# DIV Blur with inner INPUT

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю фильтр.
По клику открывается окно с чекбоксами.
При клике вне фильтра окно должно закрываться.
При клике по чекбоксам окно фильтра не должено закрываться

До шел до такого варианта и затык:

```
<style>
#toggle{
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#root{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid;
}
</style>
<div id="toggle">open/close</div>
<br>
<div id="root" tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="1"><input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1" id="1">1</label><br>
    <label for="2"><input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2" id="2">2</label><br>
    <label for="3"><input type="checkbox" name="3" value="3" id="3">3</label><br>
    <label for="4"><input type="checkbox" name="4" value="4" id="4">4</label>
</div>
<script>
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#root').fadeToggle(200,function(){
        if( $(this).is(':visible') ) $(this).focus();
    });
});

$('#root').blur(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
</script>
```

При клике по чекбоксу форма закрывается.
При чем при клике по самому чекбоксу он еще и не отмечается.
Только при клике по лейбле окно хоть и закрывается, но чекбокс отрабатывает.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3pwvrc8/)

Что то сгуглилось [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3pwvrc8/1/), но тоже не работает.
Чую идея верная, но не могу сообразить, видимо глаз замылился.
Рассчитываю на помощь.
Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#toggle").click(function () {
  function hide() {
    $("#root").hide();
  }
  
  var $root = $("#root");
  $root.toggle(!$root.is(':visible'));
  
  document.addEventListener('click', function handler() {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#root').length) {
      if(!$(event.target).closest('#toggle').length) {
        setTimeout(hide);
      }
      document.removeEventListener('click', handler, true);
    }
  }, true);
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: .25em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#root {
  display: none;
}

#toggle, #root {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .25em;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

label:hover {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="toggle">open/close</div>

<div id="root" tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="1"><input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1" id="1">1</label>
    <label for="2"><input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2" id="2">2</label>
    <label for="3"><input type="checkbox" name="3" value="3" id="3">3</label>
    <label for="4"><input type="checkbox" name="4" value="4" id="4">4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

То, что Вы пытаетесь сделать это очень распространенный элемент интерфейса - модальное окно.
Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
jQuery plugin: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal
jQueryUI: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Думал об этом. Но тянуть плагин ради этого, как то не хочется.

Comment: Можно конечно добавить bgDiv на всю страницу, но хочется довести текущее до точки.